# How I can extract Binary file from EXE file?

Tags: bios, binary-files, eeprom

I have a BIOS file .EXE and I want to extract the bainary file from it to flash it to a BIOS chip directly with USB EEPROM programmer.

- What I have tried: Extracting the EXE file with 7ZIP or WINZIP to
  look if there is a BIN file inside it, But I only find ROM file.

**I tried diffrent programs like universal extracter and the same result.
Any one have any idea how to do that?**

Comment: Why do you assume there should be a .BIN file?  ASUS motherboards, as an example, use a .ROM extension for the update file.  Is there a reason you don't want to run the mfr's standalone update utility?

Comment: I repair electronics for living, sometimes laptops came with stuck bios firmwere and we need to flash it again on external programmer to make the laptop work again, we use only BIN files to flash these chips direclty, and these files doesnt always exsist, so I need away to do it by myself

Comment: You can try [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Comment: @wysiwyg that's an awsome app, I will give it a try thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various methods for extracting the BIOS file from the installation
files. That file can have various formats: ROM, BIN, FD, CAP, BIO, WPH and EFI.

- Use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or [Uni Extract](https://bioruebe.com/dev/uniextract/).
- Find in TEMP folder:
  Many installers extract the package file into the TEMP directory. Launch the setup
  and once the first dialog or prompt is displayed, examine your TEMP directory for
  a newly created sub-directory or file. Copy that file from TEMP folder and then
  cancel the installation.
- A Dell `.exe` BIOS file can be extracted by running
  `install-file.exe /writeromfile`.
  Other known parameters are `writehdrfile` and `writehexfile`.
  Another method is to use
  [PFSExtractor](https://github.com/LongSoft/PFSExtractor).
- [This thread](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=290064.0)
  describes using the tool [B2MB](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=290064.0;attach=57811).

This is by no means an exhaustive list of all the possible formats.

Comment: The second one to look inside temp files is awesome, solved alot of errors and so clean

Answer (score 0):

**For Dell systems drivers**:

First - Download all drivers for your system from the Dell website and use those files.

Example - `"AREA51-R2_Audio_Driver_JYN2T_WN32_1.00.08_A02.exe" /s /e=E:\Dell`

Some 'exe' files will extract under the folder `production`. Some will extract to the `Drivers` folder. For those under the `Drivers` folder I then used the same option to get into the `production` folder.

FYI: One file I had removed a couple directories. This file had Windows 2000 'W2K*" files. I had to go back and redo the rest of my files.

[image: Base directory image]

[image: 'production' directory image]

[image: 'Drivers' directory image]

General Usage:
`"driver name".exe [/<option1>[=<value1>]] [/<option2>[=<value2>]]...`

See listing below for  and  information.

NOTE:If the folder name contains space, double quotes should be given for folder name
EXAMPLE: `/s /e="c:\Folder Name"`

### Option - Description:

(none) - Display of graphical user interface for guided installation/update or extraction.

`/?` or `/h` - Displays this  Update Package usage information.

`/s` - Suppresses all graphical user interfaces of the  Update Package.

`/e=<path>` - Extraction of update contents to a folder.
(NOTE: Requires `/s` option)

`/drivers=<path>` - Extraction of only driver components to a folder.
(NOTE: Requires `/s` option)

`/driveronly` - Installation/Update of the driver components only.
(NOTE: Requires `/s` option)

`/passthrough ...` - (Advanced) Sends all text following the /passthrough option directly to the vendor install software of the  Update Package. This mode suppresses any  provided graphical user interfaces, but not necessarily those of the vendor software.

`/factoryinstall /passthrough (vendor command line parameter)` - (Advanced) (commnad line parameters) will be passed to vendor installer directly without parsing MUP.xml. Post installation, If the vendor installer returns `REBOOT_REQUIRED` or `REBOOT_UPDATE_PENDING`, it will be turned to SUCCESS.

`/capabilities` - (Advanced) Returns a coded description of this  Update Package's supported features.
(NOTE: Requires `/s` option)

`/l=<path>` - Define a specific path for the  Update Package log file.
(NOTE: This option can NOT be used in combination with `/passthrough` or `/capabilities`)

### Example(s):

Update the system silently
`AREA51-R2_Audio_Driver_JYN2T_WN32_1.00.08_A02.exe /s`

Extract the update contents to the folder `C:\mydir\ AREA51-R2_Audio_Driver_JYN2T_WN32_1.00.08_A02.exe /s /e=C:\mydir`

Extract the driver components to the folder `C:\mydir\ AREA51-R2_Audio_Driver_JYN2T_WN32_1.00.08_A02.exe /s /drivers=C:\mydir`

Only install driver components
`AREA51-R2_Audio_Driver_JYN2T_WN32_1.00.08_A02.exe /s /driveronly`

Pass command line arguments directly to vendor installer.
Turn the return code to success if required
`AREA51-R2_Audio_Driver_JYN2T_WN32_1.00.08_A02.exe /factoryinstall /passthrough D:\Sample.xml C:\log\FI.log`

Change from the default log location to `C:\my path with spaces\log.txt AREA51-R2_Audio_Driver_JYN2T_WN32_1.00.08_A02.exe /l="C:\my path with spaces\log.txt"`